# JavaScript - How to show image ALT text on a div?

Tags: javascript, html, alt

I'm trying to show the `alt` text of images on the `#show` div. I want to click an image and show its `alt` in `#show`, click another image and show its `alt` and like that. How can i make it work?

```
<div id="IMGS">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <div><img src="img/frog.jpg" alt="this is a frog" height="100" /><p>0</p></div>
    <div><img src="img/bird.jpg" alt="this is a bird" height="100" /><p>0</p></div>
    <div><img src="img/Photoshop-01.jpg" alt="this ain't real" height="100" /><p>0</p></div>
    <div id="show"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You show your HTML here, but what have you tried so far in JavaScript that's not working?

Comment: *"But I can't make it work"* What have you tried? Where specifically are you stuck? Bind event handlers? Getting the alt value? Setting the content of an element?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I'm really stuck with this one.

Comment: *"I don't know how to do it."* You basically set it yourself: bind a click event handler to image, get the clicked elements alt value and update the content of the div. What specifically are you having problems with? *"I don't know how to do it."* is very broad.

Comment: The div is still empty, I tried something like this:
let show = document.getElementById('show');
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for(let img of imgs) {
  img.addEventListener('click', function() { show.innerText = img.alt });
}

Comment: @yonige : Welcome to Stack Overflow. You would need to understand JavaScript for this. Get started [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: imgs[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`. While NodeLists are theoretically iterable, no browser implements that yet afaik. Convert the list to an array first. https://jsfiddle.net/754m7ff5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, you add an event listener for each image:

```
var myImage = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var text = document.getElementById("show");

for (var i = 0; i < myImage.length; i++) {
    myImage[i].addEventListener('click',show);
}

function show(){
    var myAlt = this.alt;
    text.innerHTML = myAlt;
}
```

Check the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/2bkkr6g6/3/

Comment: Thanks. You were really helpful, is working and it's more simple than the code I was trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all images with [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and attach click handlers on them as follows:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#IMGS img');
var elem = document.getElementById('show');

images.forEach(function(image) {
  image.addEventListener('click', function() {
    elem.innerHTML = image.getAttribute('alt');
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="IMGS">
  <h2>1</h2>
  <div><img src="img/frog.jpg" alt="this is a frog" height="100" class="img" /><p>0</p></div>
  <div><img src="img/bird.jpg" alt="this is a bird" height="100" class="img" /><p>0</p></div>
  <div><img src="img/Photoshop-01.jpg" alt="this ain't real" height="100" /><p>0</p></div>
  <div id="show"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the console you will see that your code throws an error:

> imgs[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

While NodeLists are theoretically iterable, no browser implements that yet afaik. Convert the list to an array first, then it will work:

```
for (let img of Array.from(imgs)) {
  // ...
}
```

```js
let show = document.getElementById('show');
 let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
 for (let img of Array.from(imgs)) {
   img.addEventListener('click', function() {
     show.innerText = img.alt
   });
 }
```

```html
<div id="IMGS">
  <h2>1</h2>
  <div>
    <img src="img/frog.jpg" alt="this is a frog" height="100" />
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/bird.jpg" alt="this is a bird" height="100" />
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/Photoshop-01.jpg" alt="this ain't real" height="100" />
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
  <div id="show"></div>
</div>
```

**Notes**

- The standard property to set the text content is `textContent`. `innerText` is actually IE.
- `for...of` and `let` are a relatively new constructs that are not supported by every (especially older) browsers.

There is no need for them though. You can access the clicked element via `this` inside the event handler, which eliminates the need for a block scoped variable. `for...of` can be replaced by `.forEach`:

```
 var show = document.getElementById('show');
 var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
 var handler = function() { show.textContent = this.alt; };
 Array.from(imgs).forEach(function(img) { img.addEventListener('click', handler); });
```

or make use of event delegation:

```
var show = document.getElementById('show');
var imgs = document.getElementById('IMGS');
imgs.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
     show.textContent = event.target.alt;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a class for image (just a dummy one)

```
<div id="IMGS">
        <h2>1</h2>
        <div><img src="img/frog.jpg" alt="this is a frog" height="100" class="img" /><p>0</p></div>
        <div><img src="img/bird.jpg" alt="this is a bird" height="100" class="img" /><p>0</p></div>
        <div><img src="img/Photoshop-01.jpg" alt="this ain't real" height="100" /><p>0</p></div>
        <div id="show"></div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".img").click(function () {
      $("#show").html(  $(this).attr('alt'))  );
 })
```

Comment: Question doen't have a jQuery tag.

Comment: *"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to achieve that is through jQuery.

Here's the code you need:

```
var imgs = $("#IMGS img");
var show = $("#show");

imgs.on("click", function() {
show.html(this.alt);
})
```